# axWindowsMediaPlayer sometimes just play sound and sometimes show black screen

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am working on a WPF desktop application that play movie. i have used axWindowsMediaPlayer on it.
But there is a problem. Videos can not be played on some computers and axWindowsMediaPlayer just shows black screen. 
The only sound on other computers.

[image]

Of course, everything is fine on many computers.
Why sometimes just black screen to be displayed? And Why Sometimes the only sound is played?
thanks

Comment: That is a codec issue you are having

Comment: @NicoRiff is there any solution?

Comment: install a codec package on those computers